# How to send message more than 160 characters in gammu using C#

Tags: c#, multipart, gammu

i have try sent sms in **gammu**... it's simple just store data to **outbox** table and gammu will be automatic sent sms. My problem ins when my message more than 160 characters (ex. 170) My message is truncated (just sent 160 characters only).. i have try to searching on internet but i get in php code.

This is my code when i store to **outbox** table in **gammu** :

```
if (koneksidb.con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    koneksidb.con.Close();
koneksidb.con.Open();

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO outbox (DestinationNumber , TextDecoded) VALUES 
                    ('"+txtPhoneNumber+"','"+txtMessage+"')";
cmd.Connection = koneksidb.con;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Anyone can help me how to sent message more than 160 characters in gammu? Need Suggest Thanks

Comment: In general 160 is text (SMS) message size limit so you may need to send two messages.

Comment: do u have any solution if i sent message more than 160 characters my message is truncated?

Answer (score 0):

There is detailed [example in the Gammu manual](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/tables.html#injecting-long-message-using-sql).

Messages longer than 160 chars are sent as more messages and you either have to create each part manually or use Gammu SMSD API or gammu-smsd-inject to create them.

Comment: so it is mean that i must create long message
method manually?